# Qt Breakpad results

Tags: qt, google-breakpad

Im following the notes from this [url](https://github.com/JPNaude/dev_notes/wiki/Using-Google-Breakpad-with-Qt)

I have it compiled on my code (Qt, windows, VS 2015)
I run it in debug mode and when it crashes I do the following:

Create the symbol file

```
dump_syms.exe ZendeskClient.exe > ZendeskClient.sym
```

Using the dmp and the symbol file generate a text file (tried each one)

```
minidump_stackwalk.exe filename.dmp symbols > ZendeskClient.txt 2>&1
minidump_stackwalk.exe filename.dmp ZendeskClient.sym > ZendeskClient1.txt 2>&1
minidump_stackwalk.exe filename.dmp ZendeskClient.sym symbols > ZendeskClient2.txt 2>&1
```

But I dont see anything that shows what caused the crash in the app.  I see in the text (600 lines)(Its not all the information, just enough hopefully to show what i'm trying to show.  The rest of the data is somewhat the same):

```
2016-04-20 21:00:32: minidump_processor.cc:264: INFO: Processing minidump in file C:\Users\adviner\c62072b9-3bf7-42b6-b6f2-28c3ccf9546f.dmp
2016-04-20 21:00:32: minidump.cc:3500: INFO: Minidump opened minidump C:\Users\adviner\c62072b9-3bf7-42b6-b6f2-28c3ccf9546f.dmp
2016-04-20 21:00:32: minidump.cc:3545: INFO: Minidump not byte-swapping minidump
2016-04-20 21:00:32: minidump.cc:3902: INFO: GetStream: type 1197932546 not present
2016-04-20 21:00:32: minidump.cc:1945: INFO: MinidumpModule could not determine version for C:\Projects\PersonalApps\Build\Windows\ZendeskClient\debug\ZendeskClient.exe
2016-04-20 21:00:32: minidump_processor.cc:116: INFO: Minidump C:\Users\adviner\c62072b9-3bf7-42b6-b6f2-28c3ccf9546f.dmp has CPU info, OS info, 

....

CPU: x86
     GenuineIntel family 6 model 78 stepping 3
     4 CPUs

Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ
Crash address: 0xffffffffcdcdcddd

Thread 0 (crashed)
 0  ntdll.dll + 0x76bfc
    eip = 0x77bc6bfc   esp = 0x0018bb08   ebp = 0x0018bb78   ebx = 0x00000001
    esi = 0x00000000   edi = 0x000001fc   eax = 0x00000000   ecx = 0xcdcdcddd
    edx = 0x0018c570   efl = 0x00200202
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  KERNELBASE.dll + 0xae131
    eip = 0x7795e132   esp = 0x0018bb80   ebp = 0x0018bb8c
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 2  ZendeskClient.exe + 0xfcf3f
    eip = 0x002fcf40   esp = 0x0018bb94   ebp = 0x0018bba4
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 3  ZendeskClient.exe + 0xfc9e7
    eip = 0x002fc9e8   esp = 0x0018bbac   ebp = 0x0018bbe4
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 4  KERNELBASE.dll + 0x13f471
    eip = 0x779ef472   esp = 0x0018bbec   ebp = 0x0018bc74
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 5  ntdll.dll + 0xa35ed
    eip = 0x77bf35ee   esp = 0x0018bc7c   ebp = 0x0018fb8c
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 6  ntdll.dll + 0x65dad
    eip = 0x77bb5dae   esp = 0x0018fb94   ebp = 0x0018fb9c
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer

...

Loaded modules:
0x00200000 - 0x003e9fff  ZendeskClient.exe  ???  (main)
0x00bf0000 - 0x00d62fff  ucrtbased.dll  10.0.10240.16384
0x02490000 - 0x024b2fff  WINMMBASE.dll  6.2.10586.0
0x02650000 - 0x0266cfff  qicnsd.dll  5.6.0.0
0x029d0000 - 0x02bc8fff  qwindowsd.dll  5.6.0.0
0x02d50000 - 0x02d68fff  qicod.dll  5.6.0.0
0x02d70000 - 0x02d85fff  qsvgd.dll  5.6.0.0
0x02d90000 - 0x02da4fff  qtgad.dll  5.6.0.0
0x02dd0000 - 0x02f0efff  dbghelp.dll  6.2.10586.0
```

Is there something wrong in the way i'm building the output?  Im on windows btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is general to debug practice on Windows. Microsoft Visual C++ build tools produce [Program Database File](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/08/whats-inside-a-pdb-file/) format output when you compile/link your project. And then when the program crashes you get .dmp or minidump file you can unwind the stack with specific function names / lines.

How to do the actual debug having the dump file? You can use this answer as Wiki for debugging using both dmp and pdb files: [Analyzing Crash dumps in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252407/analyzing-crash-dumps-in-visual-studio). Just open dump file with Visual Studio and then point to program database and then source code and you will see the picture of all threads/stacks at the moment of crash.

UPDATE: We can also 'symbolicate' the 'empty' dump without names as answered: [stackwalker loads all symbol files, but still doesn't symbolicate anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537187/stackwalker-loads-all-symbol-files-but-still-doesnt-symbolicate-anything). I guess that the tool name is [minidump_stackwalk](https://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps).

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed to see the problem.  You rock :)

Comment: We do that and recalled that there is a way to produce better text output as well. Added an Update.

Comment: @AlexanderVX unfortunately the minidump_stackwalk still does not give me the results. In fact I am doing something wrong where I cannot use VS2015 as well. I am completely stuck here. My problem is exactly as described above. Any help would be appreciated please.